# Short Story - alien contact, offer to provide extra/third prehensile eye

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a (probably short) story which I read in the late 70's or early 80's which involved aliens visiting earth and offering biological enhancements.

I recall that the main character (a boy?) had a third eye attached to the top of his head (on a prehensile stalk) and that it had telescopic vision (as well as other advanced optics compared to a human eye). The parents are very unhappy about this especially as the boy enthuses about how wonderful it is. Eventually they decide to forcibly have it removed and I believe the boy is drugged unconscious. If I recall correctly, the last lines of the story are about the father carrying the unconscious boy out of his room, over his shoulder, and feeling the limp eye stalk bouncing on his back.