# Sci-fi anthology book with a story about a boy given a third eye by aliens, and another story with a female spaceship commander and canine-like aliens

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book

I've been reminded recently of a sci-fi anthology book I had/read many years ago. Pretty sure its from the '80s (I'm in the UK). I don't have many details except vague memories of 2 stories.

The first is about a child/boy (teen?) living on, staying at, or visiting an alien world with his parents. The locals have a 3rd eye and they give the boy a 3rd while he sleeps.

The second is about a female spaceship commander who encounters an unknown spaceship in the vicinity of Earth and the aliens turn out to be canine/dog-like in appearance (there's bit of twist that I recall and kind thought was cool but I won't post here as spoiler just in case).

Comment: Welcome to the site. You should go ahead post the spoiler. The more information we have about the stories, the easier it'll be to find them.

Comment: You can [edit] in any extra details or change what you already have if you want to! You can hide any potential spoilers as well by putting a `>!` at the start of the paragraph. I'd also recommend changing the title to something a bit more descriptive!

Comment: The first one sounds like my question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/247351/short-story-alien-contact-offer-to-provide-extra-third-prehensile-eye (which didn't get any answers) but I don't recall the second one.

Comment: AdamT I've read your question and yes I'd agree it sounds very similar to the one I'm thinking of, but I couldn't say 100% for certain, but do think it would be a hugh percentage.  In relation to the second story I recall the twist/ending was that everything up to a point was some kind of simulated first contact test (something a kin to the Kobyashi Maru from Star Tek) to see how someone would react in this situation. I don't recall the exact details as its I remember reading 25 - 30 years plus ago. But I'm almost certain both were part of an anthology book of science fiction stories.